# mySQL Insert failing : UUID becoming null on save() method with Doctrine and Symfony 6.0

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been scratching my head over the past hour or so on this bug. I'm new to a Symfony project (and Symfony in general) and we are storing our data in a mySQL database, and some of our tables are using UUIDS for id in both primary and foreign key fields.

Here is some sample code from the project :

```php
    public function createChannelHistory($consentParams, string $channelId, string $channelLabel): void
    {
        $channelHistory = new ChannelHistory();
        $channelHistoryId = Uuid::v6();
        $channelHistory->setId((string) $channelHistoryId);
        $channelHistory->setChannelId($channelId);
        $channelHistory->setLabel('Promotional ' . $channelLabel);
        $channelHistory->setIsOptIn($consentParams[$channelLabel . '_opt_in']);
        $channelHistory->setCreatedAt(new Carbon());

        var_dump('channelId : ' . $channelId, 'channelHistoryId : ' .     $channelHistory->getId());


        $this->channelHistoryRepository->save($channelHistory);
    }
```

Dumping both variables yields this : "string(48) "channelId : 1ecec3c8-71aa-61be-8f38-2f921a413b0f" string(60) " /// channelHistoryId : 1ecec3c8-71c8-6448-924f-2f921a413b0f"".

However, when reaching the save method, it seems $channelId gets replaced to null somehow, and insertion fails because our channel_id column in table is set to NOT NULL.

dev.log file contains this :

```
[2022-06-15T01:51:26.554679+02:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: INSERT INTO channel_history (id, channel_id, label, is_opt_in, created_at, created_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) (parameters: array{"1":"\u001e���u�g������\b?�","2":null,"3":"Promotional mail","4":0,"5":"2022-06-15 01:51:26","6":null}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2,"4":5,"5":2,"6":2}) {"sql":"INSERT INTO channel_history (id, channel_id, label, is_opt_in, created_at, created_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)","params":{"1":"\u001e���u�g������\b?�","2":null,"3":"Promotional mail","4":0,"5":"2022-06-15 01:51:26","6":null},"types":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2,"4":5,"5":2,"6":2}} []
[2022-06-15T01:51:26.560858+02:00] app.ERROR: An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'channel_id' cannot be null
```

As you can see, right before the query both variables exist and are of type string, with values resembling what they should be.
I'm at a loss as to why the second id becomes null when running the query.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the relationship between `ChannelHistory` and `channelId`? If `Channel` is an entity, check the doc about [ManyToOne and entity](https://symfony.com/doc/6.1/doctrine/associations.html#mapping-the-manytoone-relationship), you should pass the instance of the entity, not an id. Doctrine will handle it. Otherwise, please edit your question and explain the relationships.

Comment: Yeah, i should probably have read that before spending time scratching my head. Thanks a lot for the answer, solved it right away. Gonna look up more stuff about doctrine, thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the relationship between ChannelHistory and channelId? If Channel is an entity, check the doc about [ManyToOne and entity](https://symfony.com/doc/6.1/doctrine/associations.html#mapping-the-manytoone-relationship), you should pass the instance of the entity, not an id. Doctrine will handle it.

Set the association between `ChannelHistory` and `Channel`:

```php
// src/Entity/ChannelHistory.php
namespace App\Entity;

// ...
class ChannelHistory
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Channel", inversedBy="histories")
     */
    private $channel;

    public function getChannel ?Channel
    {
        return $this->channel;
    }

    public function setChannel(?Channel $channel): self
    {
        $this->channel = $channel;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to pass the entity directly to the function and to the entity:

```php
    public function createChannelHistory($consentParams, Channel $channel, string $channelLabel): void
    {
        $channelHistory = new ChannelHistory();
        // …
        $channelHistory->setChannel($channel);
        // …
    }
```